# Where to put common beans(POJOs) to be reloaded during development as other classes like Pages etc

Tags: tapestry

Where to put common beans(POJOs) to be reloaded during development as other classes like Pages etc. I have a simple beans I use in page classes but not where to put them to be reloaded by Tapestry during development. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tapestry can only hot deploy pages, components, mixins and service implementations. It does this through clever use of a disposable classloader and service proxies. It can not reload service interfaces or POJO's, these require a JVM restart.

If you want to hot deploy everything, you'll need a JVM plugin like [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/)